# How to playback MP4 file in Mpeg4 Part 14 format?

Tags: apple, mp4

I have some mp4 video files that come from my iPad.  I am wanting to play them on Linux.  By default, the player doesn't recognise the format.

```
$ file 1.1.1.mp4
1.1.1.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

What can play them, or how do I convert them to a format that can be played?  I've tried VLC.  And Totem.  Both don't recognise the format.

```
$ mediainfo -f 1.1.1.mp4
General
Count                                    : 322
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Complete name                            : 1.1.1.mp4
File name                                : 1.1.1
File extension                           : mp4
File size                                : 113901589
File size                                : 109 MiB
File size                                : 109 MiB
File size                                : 109 MiB
File size                                : 109 MiB
File size                                : 108.6 MiB
Stream size                              : 113901589
Stream size                              : 109 MiB (100%)
Stream size                              : 109 MiB
Stream size                              : 109 MiB
Stream size                              : 109 MiB
Stream size                              : 108.6 MiB
Stream size                              : 109 MiB (100%)
Proportion of this stream                : 1.00000
File last modification date              : UTC 2017-04-02 08:10:35
File last modification date (local)      : 2017-04-02 20:10:35


ffprobe version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x9bc8e0] moov atom not found
1.1.1.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input


$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture} ${Version}\n' 'gstreamer*-plugins-*' | sed -ne 's/^i //p'
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr:amd64 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1


matthewh@xen:~/Desktop$ mkvmerge -o 1.1.1.mkv \( 1.1.1.mp4 \)
mkvmerge v8.8.0 ('Wind at my back') 64bit
'1.1.1.mp4': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'QuickTime/MP4'.
Error: Quicktime/MP4 reader: Have not found the 'mdat' atom. No movie data found.
```

Comment: The 'file' description,(MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]),  isn't useful. Maybe open the file in mediainfo & add info to your post (view > text to copy & paste from.

Comment: What's the output of `ffprobe 1.1.1.mp4` (or `avprobe` if you're on Ubuntu Trusty)? What's the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}:${Architecture} ${Version}\n' 'gstreamer*-plugins-*' | sed -ne 's/^i //p'`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster  output added.  The ffprobe output looks interesting. hmm.

Comment: That moov atom not found seems to indicate corruption.  But on the iPad it plays fine.  So either the file is being corrupted when copied or all the players are just broken or apple is doing something non-standard?  any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe Mkvmerge can still salvage something useful since it uses a different MPEG4 parser. What's the output of `mkvmerge -o 1.1.1.mkv \( 1.1.1.mp4 \)`? If successful, can you play back `1.1.1.mkv` in Totem or VLC Player?

Comment: That didn't work.  See above.  Maybe the file is encrypted?

Comment: It uses a custom player app.  The only reason to copy it to the linux machine is so I can cast it to chromecast since these files are not in a path that localcast can see.

Comment: I have a Mac laptop.  I'll try copying the file there and see if it plays.

Comment: Can you upload the file somewhere?